# Next.js sends duplicate (redundant) chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, client-side

I experience an issue in my web app, where 80% of the .js chunks are loaded twice, redundantly without a clear reason.

Clearly this increases TTI and hits my Lighthouse score.

These dups are identical in `Name`, `Path` and `Size`.
They differ in `Initiator` and `Type` (`javascript` and not `script`), as seen in this image:

[image]

Looks like this issue has been reported already (e.g. [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7392) and [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11107)), but it's not clear if Vercel addresses the problem in these bug reports.

When following [this suggestion to disable link prefetch](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7392#issuecomment-963928397) I did manage to see the problem go away, but so did the prefetch (which still works on hover).

Is there anything I could do differently to benefit from `Next's link prefetch` while not experiencing these redundant .js chunks?

Is this addressed in Next.js version 12?

More info about my setup:

- Next.js version 10.2.3.
- React version 16.12.0.
- [Serving statically from AWS S3](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).
- [Rendering everything on the client side](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side).
- Code splitting to .js chunks is made by Next.js, and I'm using the default route based (/pages) code splitting. No [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) is used at this point.

More info about the issue:

- It does not repro when you refresh page, since browser caches these chunks.
- No repro on Firefox.
- Seems like it’s [happening in version 11 too](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7392#issuecomment-895934747). Also [10 and 9, but not 8](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7392#issuecomment-990655405).